# Upload a track to SoundCloud with post request from Node.js to SC API

Tags: javascript, node.js, soundcloud

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so let me apologize in advance for any faux pas. (I'd be grateful for any comments about how I could improve this question.) Also, thanks so much for taking a look!

For the last couple of days I've been trying to upload a song to SoundCloud from Node.js with no success.

The really frustrating part is that I AM able to make the request from the front-end using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK. (The only reason I'm making the post from the backend is because I ultimately need to be able to schedule the 'POST' request to be made at a later date from the server).

I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to upload a song with a POST request via the API. I suspect that it might only be possible via the SDK, which, as best as I can tell, isn't available in Node.

For one thing, in the API documentation, it doesn't list 'POST' as an available method on the ['/track' route](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users). This can be found in the 'Subresources' table at the bottom of the '/tracks' section. (On the other hand, I'm wondering if it's possible to upload a song with a PUT request. I thought PUT was only for updates, but while reading some AWS docs, I noticed that objects can be uploaded to an S3 bucket with a POST request from the client or a PUT request from the server. This would still be consistent with the SC docs since they suggest using a POST with the SDK from the front-end, but don't list POST as an option in the API.)

However in the [SDK documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading-files) it says:

> To upload a sound, send a POST request to the /tracks endpoint. This
>   is done with one of our SDKs using the post method and passing
>   information about the track being uploaded.

I tried utilizing the node-soundcloud and the soundclouder npm packages with no success. I'm able to authenticate the user and make a GET request to the '/me' route (which, I'm almost certain I shouldn't be able to do without authenticating).

The following example is with node-soundcloud, but soundclouder is nearly identical.

```
    SC.init({
        id: client_id, 
        secret: client_secret, 
        uri: redirect_uri,
        accessToken: body.fields.accessToken
    });
    SC.get('/me/activities', function(err, data){
        if ( err ) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log("data", data);
            res.end();
        }
    })
```

However, I'm not able to make a 'POST' request to the '/tracks' route.

```
    SC.post('/tracks', {
        'title': 'test title',
        'asset_data': body.file.buffer
    }, function(err, data){
        console.log("data", data);
        res.end();
    })
```

This returns

```
{ errors: [ { error_message: '401 - Unauthorized' } ] }
```

I've opened 'issues' via both of their Githubs. (Node-soundcloud has actually been really helpful in trying to resolve this.)

My most recent attempt has been to try to imitate the successful front-end attempt by constructing an HTTP request in Postman. Even this isn't working. In Postman I'm getting this error: "Request entity contains invalid byte sequence. Please transmit valid UTF-8."

I get the same error, when I try to make the request from Node.js using the 'request' npm library.

Here's data from the successful request from the front-end that I pulled out of the Network tab in chrome dev tools. (Realizing that you can convert a request into a curl post from dev tools was pretty great!):

```
General
Headers
Request URL:https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Remote Address:72.21.91.127:443

Request Headers
POST /tracks? HTTP/1.1
Host: api.soundcloud.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 73945
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:1337
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:1337/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="track[asset_data]"; filename="test2.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3


------WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="track[title]"

6:14
------WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format"

json
------WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="oauth_token"

(THIS IS WHERE THE ACCESS TOKEN GOES)
------WebKitFormBoundary6zA9wPyul1LgLYTW--
```

Finally, I found this [other question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159979/soundcloud-http-api-post-tracks-422-unprocessable) which seems to suggest that I might need to "frame" the track as a "recording" made on Soundcloud.

Please let me know if there's any additional information that would be helpful for me to upload. Thanks very much in advance for your help!